# Invalid update_mask. - how to specify a JSON update mask correctly for googleapis?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm trying to use the following API:
https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.accessLevels/patch

My goal is simple: update ("patch") an "AccessLevel" object in GCP's backend.

I am calling the API using "UrlFetchApp.fetch" method from Google's Apps Script:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com/v1/accessPolicies/12345678/accessLevels/User_A_Home_IP?updateMask=updateMask',options);
```

where "options" (passed as the 2nd param after the url endpoint) is:

```
  var options = 
  {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    payload : JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    "updateMask" : "*"
   }
```

and "payload" is:

```
var payload=
  {
    "basic": {
      "combiningFunction": "OR",
      "conditions": [
      {
        "ipSubnetworks": [
          "11.12.13.14/32"
        ]
      }
      ]
    },
  "name": "accessPolicies/12345678/accessLevels/User_A_Home_IP",
  "title": "User A Home IP"
  }
```

The result I'm getting back is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid update_mask. All paths must be in the AccessLevel message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

According to the documentation (first link in this post)
The request body should contain an instance of AccessLevel (this is the "payload" object in my code)
Also required is an "updateMask" query parameter which indicates which fields of the backend target json object get updated.

updateMask, If I understand correctly - is of Type FieldMask:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask

I only need to update the single IP address found in the "ipSubnetworks" array of strings, that in turn is found inside the "conditions" array of objects, which in turn is nested under the "basic" object.

What is the correct syntax for updateMask in this case?

Where should updateMask be located in my "PATCH" request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specify in the `updateMask` the main fields you would like to update

If you update more than one field - specify all fields comma separated (without spaces inbetween).

In your case:

`"updateMask" : "basic,title"`

See also:

[updateMask](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.accessLevels/patch#query-parameters)

> string (FieldMask format)

> Required. Mask to control which fields get updated. Must be non-empty.

> This is a comma-separated list of fully qualified names of fields. Example: "user.displayName,photo".

Sample JSON:

```
"name": "accessPolicies/12345678/accessLevels/User_A_Home_IP",
"updateMask": "basic,title",
"title": "User A Home IP",
"resource": {
      "basic": {
          "combiningFunction": "OR",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "ipSubnetworks": [
                "11.12.13.14/32"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

**UPDATE:**

A sample Apps Script function:

```js
function patchResource() {
    var options = 
  {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    payload : JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions : true
   }
    
    var payload=
  {
"name": "accessPolicies/12345678/accessLevels/User_A_Home_IP",
"updateMask": "basic,title",
"title": "User A Home IP",
"resource": {
      "basic": {
          "combiningFunction": "OR",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "ipSubnetworks": [
                "11.12.13.14/32"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }
    
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com/v1/accessPolicies/12345678/accessLevels/User_A_Home_IP',options);
  console.log(result.getResponseCode())
  console.log(result.getContentText())
}
```

If you do want to pass the updateMask as a URL parameter instead of part of the payload - make sure to URL encode the comma:

`?updateMask=basic%2Ctitle`

Comment: Thanks I've tried exactly that, only "basic" on the updatemaske field, and still got the same response, I believe some of the solution is to know exactly where in relation to the root object i'm trying to update - to place the updateMask field, and also do it in the supported syntax (alas, could not find proper documentation for this in this API)

Comment: I tested it with exactly the same request like yours and it worked for me. Maybe you can test with the [Try This API](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.accessLevels/patch) first - to exclude coding / syntax errors?

Comment: Mind sharing the full solution then? or just the full JSON object you sent in your request, including headers and such? the full JSON should suffice for me, thanks!

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.accessLevels/patch?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22accessPolicies%2F12345678%2FaccessLevels%2FUser_A_Home_IP%22%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22basic%2Ctitle%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22basic%22%3A%7B%22combiningFunction%22%3A%22OR%22%2C%22conditions%22%3A%5B%7B%22ipSubnetworks%22%3A%5B%2211.12.13.14%2F32%22%5D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22title%22%3A%22User%20A%20Home%20IP%22%7D%7D#query-parameters

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, I tried using the "Try This API" sidebar, but in it the fields are separate and I can't seem to figure out how to "translate" the various fields in this form (mainly the body of the request and the updateMask and the relation between them) to a JSON object that can be sent along as the request's data.
That's why I've asked for the full JSON, I thought you tested it with some command line client (cURL?) or a programing langugue of some kind.

Comment: I provided the JSON in my updated response above.

Comment: I do see the body JSON in the link you provided, but the updateMask field is not a part of it, i am wondering exactly that - how to build the JSON that's sent through my request, specifically how to place the updateMask inside that JSON in relation to the object that i'm trying to update on the server side....

having just the BODY JSON and the updateMask on a seprate UI field doesn't help me understand how to place them in a single JSON that can be sent via a programming language/script , that's the only reason I keep asking for a full json object, not a json object and some other ui fields

Comment: The JSON body (in the answer, not in the comment) is the complete resource body. There is no need to specify the update mask in the URL (though you can). I will post now the complete Apps Script function to make it more clear.

Comment: Did you try your solution against the API and it worked?
I'm only asking because the documentation says updateMask in the URL paramaters is Mandatory.. I tried your exact solution and it didn't work for me - the error stated that updateMask is missing from url paramaters.. "message": "Must specify update_mask." .
I tried adding updateMask=basic (no need for title in my case) to the url parameters but it fails with 400 "message": "Access level must be either basic or custom."
so I'm still pretty sure the entire issue is with the hierarchy structure of the JSON object, how to construct it..

Comment: ok, got it to work, had some time to thumble around and play with it a bit and this version is working:
URL Param is mandatory so i've added:
?updateMask=basic  to the url params.
options object contains a 'payload' object:
'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
and data is simply:
var data = {"basic":{"conditions":[{"ipSubnetworks":["11.12.13.15/32"]}]}}
This one works!
I'll mark your reply as the answer, please edit it so that this reflects in the answer!
Thank you very much for all the effort!

Comment: Instead of adding updateMask to the URL parameters did you try to specify it within payload as in my solution? Adn did you test with the [Try This API](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.accessLevels/patch?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22accessPolicies%2F12345678%2FaccessLevels%2FUser_A_Home_IP%22%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22basic%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D#query-parameters)?

Comment: Just saw your other comment: Not sure what you mean by `?updateMask=basic options object contains a 'payload' object`. Do you mean that the `updateMask` shall be inside the payload?

Comment: I mean that updateMask must be a URL parameter, it can't be a json field, documentation  says updateMask is REQUIRED as URL parameter in this API. So I just added it with =basic because basic is the only field i want updated.
Other than that, just made sure that the "access level" object is an object called "payload" inside the "options" object.

Comment: also, found out that chrome developer tools lets you copy api requests made by web pages, so I used the API explorer form which worked, and using developer tools I was able to copy the API call to curl format and look at it, from that I got to the solution.
You helped me very much along the way so thank you very much for that!

Comment: I've added the working solution here as another answer, leaving yours as the accepted answer regardless.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateAccessLevelIp(accessLevelName, ip) {
  var data = {"basic":{"conditions":[{"ipSubnetworks":[ip]}]}}
  var options =
  {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
   }
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com/v1/accessPolicies/xxxxxxxxxxx/accessLevels/"+accessLevelName+"?updateMask=basic",options);
  console.log(result.getResponseCode())
  console.log(result.getContentText())
  if (result.getResponseCode() == 200)
    return ("Successfully updated the \"" + accessLevelName + "\" access level with ip address: \"" +  ip + "\"");
  else 
    return ("Failed to update \"" + accessLevelName + "\"! please talk to your friendly neighborhood DevOps team!\nResponse Code was:\n"+result.getResponseCode()+"\nResponse text was:\n"+result.getContentText());
}
```

This is working 100%: it returns http 200 and updates the ip of the access level object as wanted.

- There is No need for any special json field to be an "update mask";
  An update mask is indeed mandatory for this API call, but only as a URL parameter (Not as a json field)